Integration in high dimensional (n>3) space where integration region is defined by multiple hyperplanes
I'm new to applying integration in high dimension especially larger than 3.
Being quite desperate, I searched a lot about it but could not find the clear answer.
The problem is, I want to integrate a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, for $n\gt 3$, where the integration region is specified by $m$ hyperplanes including origin, e.g.,  $\mathbf{c}_{i}\cdot\mathbf{x}\geq 0$ for $\mathbf{c}_{i}, \textbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $i=1,2,...,m$. The number $m$ of hyperplanes can be arbitrary, it can be larger than, equal to, or less than the domain dimension $n$.
If I use the Riemann integral, what should I write for the limits of the integration? That is, if I say $\textbf{x}=(x_1,x_2, ..., x_n)$, then what should be $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s for $$\int_{a_1}^{b_1} \int_{a_2}^{b_2}... \int_{a_n}^{b_n} f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \, dx_{1}dx_{2}...dx_{n}$$?

If there is a clear answer please let me know.
If it is generally very difficult, please tell me also.
If there is a good reference, it will be welcomed.

Thank you in advance.

Several hyperplanes can limit several sets in space, therefore, for integration it is not enough to have only equations, but you also need to indicate the region of integration. Fikhtenholts, III volume of "A Course of Differential and Integral Calculus" have good examples.
